# How does java.net.URL open a connection? Does it use a socket?

Tags: java, json, url, networking

I'm using the following code to get a JSON string from a URL:

```
public static String getStringFromURL(String addr) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    URL url = new URL(addr);
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(url.openStream(), output);
    return output.toString();
}
```

I want to make sure this doesn't hang if the page at "addr" fails for any reason. I don't want it to bring our server down or anything. We started looking into how java.net.URL opens the connection and couldn't tell much from the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) (we are using 1.5). Any thoughts or inside knowledge would be appreciated. If you can cite sources, so much the better. Thanks!

Comment: then you should take a look at the code

Comment: A socket *must* be used for HTTP and the operation *must* block in that construct -- taking 200ms to resolve an address and open a connection might not mean a failure. I believe in this case the appropriate action is to use a construct which supports a *timeout* set to an appropriate value. (Default timeouts tend to be ridiculously long) -- As far are the rest: Look at the [URL.openStream documention](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) (and if this doesn't open a socket, where *does* the stream come from?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, that depends on the protocol. For HTTP, it uses TCP/IP sockets. The `openStream()` will throw an exception if an I/O error occurs. Just put it in a try/catch. However, if the server returns for example a HTTP 404 (not found) or 500 (internal error), you will get this plain into the string unawarely. You may want to use `HttpURLConnection` instead for more fine-grained control.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

if (connection.getResponseStatus() == 200) {
    // All OK, convert connection.getInputStream() to string.
    // Don't forget to take character encoding into account!
} else {
    // Possible server error. Throw exception yourself? Or return some default?
}
```

Further you can set the timeout [`URLConnection#setConnectTimeout()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29). I believe, it defaults to 3 seconds or something. You may want to tweak it to make it all faster. Set with `1000` for 1 second.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will hang.

There are two timeouts to consider:

- The connection timeout: The server may neither accept (ACK) nor reject (RST) the connection because it is firewalled. This is rather short and can be set using [setConnectTimeout()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29);
- The timeout the connection waits for data. This one is rather long (5 minutes) and is the usual thing that fails, for example if the webapplication is waiting for a database connection from a pool. It can be set using [setReadTimeout()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)